# Retrieve values from array of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to process a json file like below and extract its data in the below output format for further processing.

**json file**

```
{
    "application_robotics-2.1.610.80350109": [
        "/home/machine_process/application_robotics/services/linear_service/4.106.50109987/robotics.yaml",
        "/home/machine_process/application_robotics/services/linear_service/4.106.50109987/application_robotics-4.106.50109987.zip"
    ],
    "web_robotics-3.116.50100987": [
        "/home/machine_process/application_robotics/services/web_robotics/3.116.50100987/robotics.yaml",
        "/home/machine_process/application_robotics/services/web_robotics/3.116.50100987/web_robotics-3.116.50100987.zip"
    ]
}
```

**Expected output format**

```
name = "application_robotics-2.1.610.80350109" # where name is a variable to be used in the other portion of the code.
yaml = "/home/machine_process/application_robotics/services/linear_service/4.106.50109987/robotics.yaml" # where yaml is a variable.
zip = "/home/machine_process/application_robotics/services/linear_service/4.106.50109987/application_robotics-4.106.50109987.zip"  # where zip is a variable.
```

same format applied for other entries.

Below is the snippet code I've come up with and I'm not exactly getting the logic. Any help will be really helpful here. Thanks.

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    with open(file_path, "r") as input_json:
        json_data = json.load(input_json)
        for key, value in json_data.items():
            name = json_data[key]
            yaml = json_data[value]
            zip = json_data[value]
            file_location = os.path.dirname(tar)
            futures = executor.submit(
                other_function_name, yaml, zip, file_location, name
            )
            results.append(futures)
```

Current Output:

```
['home/machine_process/application_robotics/services/linear_service/4.106.50109987/robotics.yaml', '/home/machine_process/application_robotics/services/linear_service/4.106.50109987/application_robotics-4.106.50109987.zip']
```

Comment: @enke : I've update the question with further piece of code. Looking to get those 3 values in to a variable and feed it to a different function inside a multiprocessing loop.

Comment: avoid using `zip` as a variable name. It overrides the builtin.

Comment: thanks for pointing out, I just realised my IDE pointed out the same :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `name` corresponds to the keys; `yaml` to the first element of lists; and `zip_` to the second elements (note that `zip` is a python builtin, so avoid using it as a variable name), we can directly unpack it as we loop over the dictionary and pass these to `executor`.

```py
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    with open(file_path, "r") as input_json:
        json_data = json.load(input_json)
        for name, (yaml, zip_) in json_data.items():
            file_location = os.path.dirname(tar)
            futures = executor.submit(other_function_name, yaml, zip_, file_location, name)
            results.append(futures)
```